# inline-block cleared from float if content too wide

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a message template as below.

```
<div class='message'>
    <div class='from'>
        <i class='avatar'></i>
        <span>Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class='body'>
        <div class='content'>Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>

.message { clear: both; }    
.from {  
    float: left;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.from > i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
.from > span {
    display: block;
    width: $avatar-width;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.body {
    position: relative;
}
.body > .content {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm having a hard time making the content and div.from staying in the same line. When content is too wide, the content will go to a new line. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/9h3HN/1/ for what I mean.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try following?

```
.form {
    width: 54px;
}
.body {
    padding-left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is simple and great. .body padding will solve the problem. Thanks.